# Visual Studio 2013 & Krypton Toolkit (c#)

Tags: visual-studio, krypton-toolkit

I've added the toolkit.dll as a reference, but I can't seem to find out how to make the program inherit the ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonForm so that the over all form's design is different. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the base class of your forms from `Form` to `KryptonForm`.